# catch (NotFoundException e) is Not working for my case

Tags: android, image, try-catch

My application is showing images one after one the name of images are a1, a2, a3...an, I'm trying to catch exception when the number of images lasts but it doesn't work for me.
here's the code:

```
imagename = getIntent().getExtras().getString("somekey");

    resId = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename + num, "drawable",
            getPackageName());

    try {
        i10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                image1.setImageResource(resId);
                num++;
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushin, R.anim.pushout);

            }
        });
    } catch (NotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        i10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushinhorizontal,
                        R.anim.pushouthorizontal);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to catch exceptions inside the click listener outside what will never work

Comment: Putting all the codes in `try - catch` block is not **Exception Management**

Comment: So what's the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your try block is handling the assignment of the listener not getting resource identifier

You should do this

```
imagename = getIntent().getExtras().getString("somekey");

i10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resID = 0;
        try{
            resId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(imagename + num, "drawable", getPackageName());
        }catch (NotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(resId > 0){
            image1.setImageResource(resId);
            num++;
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushin, R.anim.pushout);
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushinhorizontal,
                    R.anim.pushouthorizontal); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not understand why you are using  if(resId > 0), as it is always resId > 0, the question is when we click on i10 and we reached the last image a60 for example, it should automatically catch the exception and move back to the menu.

Comment: Then put the try catch block inside the `onClick` method. see my edit

Comment: When the last image comes and no next image is found then your `Menu` activity will be launched. When no image is found then `resID` will be 0 and your activity will be launched

Comment: It's showing an error message:  NotFoundException cannot be resolved to a  type, it the same error of my first code

Comment: Are you importing `android.content.res.Resources`?

Comment: See if it works for you now. If it does please don't forget to accept it as answer... :D

Comment: the error now is in the else: Syntax error on token "else", delete this 
 token

Comment: Forgot {  afer if statement and after try statement. Add it.

Comment: Yes I do it by my self, but man I will become totally mad, the error of notfoundexception is again : NotFoundException cannot be resolved to a 
 type